# Redux toolkit doesn't update the state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Even if I fetch posts successfully from the api and save the response to the state using dispatcher. The state didn't update. In Feed it shows No posts found, but in posts.js (line 11) it console log the state with posts array

`Feed.js`

```
export default function Feed() {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(()=>{
    const postsFetch = async () => {
      const res = await fetch("/api/posts?author&likes",{
        headers:{
          "authorization": "Bearer "+user.token,
          "Content-Type":"application/json",
        }
      })
      const data = await res.json();
      dispatch(postActions.setPosts(data))
    }
    postsFetch();
  },[])
  const contextPosts = useSelector(s=>s.posts)
  const user = useSelector(s=>s.user)
  console.log(user)
  console.log(contextPosts)
  return (
    <div class="container pt-4 pb-4">
      {contextPosts.length == 0 && <h5 className="text-muted">No posts found</h5> }
      {contextPosts.map(d=>(
      <Post data={d} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

`posts.js | posts slice`

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

let initialState = []

export const postsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "posts",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setPosts: (state, action) => {
      state = action.payload;
      console.log(state)
    },
  },
});

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const postActions = postsSlice.actions;

export default postsSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Redux-Toolkit state slice reducers you should either *mutate* the state object ***or*** *return* the next state object reference (***but not both***). The issue with your reducer code is that you are simply reassigning the state reference. See [Direct State Mutation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#direct-state-mutation) for more details.

Example:

```js
const initialState = {
  property: { ... }
};
```

- Mutate the state reference

  ```js
  export const stateSlice = createSlice({
    name: "state",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
      stateAction: (state, action) => {
        state.property = action.payload;
      },
    },
  });
  ```
- Return a new state reference

  ```js
  export const statesSlice = createSlice({
    name: "state",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
      stateAction: (state, action) => {
        return {
          ...state,
          property: action.payload;
        };
      },
    },
  });
  ```

Since the state in your `postSlice` is an array you won't be able to mutate it, so you'll be *returning* the `action.payload` *as* the next state.

```js
export const postsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "posts",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setPosts: (state, action) => {
      return action.payload;
    },
  },
});
```

You should also keep in mind that in RTK slice reducers that you are editing a draft copy of the state, so trying to `console.log(state)` won't log the state, but rather the draft proxy object you are editing. If you want to log intermediate state changes then use the [`current`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/other-exports#current) which is a re-export of the `current` function from the immer library. See [Logging draft state values](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#logging-draft-state-values).

Example:

Action

```js
{
  payload: "bar"
}
```

```js
import { current } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  property: "foo"
};

...

stateAction: (state, action) => {
  console.log(current(state)); // { property: "foo" }
  state.property = action.payload;
  console.log(current(state)); // { property: "bar" }
},
```